# XML string array deserialize as different type name

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, deserialization

I have the following **C#** class property:

```
private List<string>  _accountTypes;

[XmlArray(ElementName = "accountTypes")]
public List<string> AccountTypes
{
   get { return _accountTypes; }
   set { _accountTypes = value; }
}
```

which is initialized like this in the class constructor:

```
_accountTypes       = new List<string>( new string[] { "OHGEE", "OHMY", "GOLLY", "GOLLYGEE" });
```

When deserialized I get this:

```
<accountTypes>
   <string>OHGEE</string>
   <string>OHMY</string>
   <string>GOLLY</string>
   <string>GOLLYGEE</string>
</accountTypes>
```

I should like it if I could get this:

```
<accountTypes>
   <accountType>OHGEE</accountType>
   <accountType>OHMY</accountType>
   <accountType>GOLLY</accountType>
   <accountType>GOLLYGEE</accountType>
</accountTypes>
```

Without creating a subclass of type "accountType", how can this be done? Are there any XML attribute properties that can be used to get what I need?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you are searching for the `[XmlArrayItem]` Attribute.

Try this:

```
[XmlArray(ElementName = "accountTypes")]
[XmlArrayItem("accountType")]
public List<string> AccountTypes
{
   get { return _accountTypes; }
   set { _accountTypes = value; }
}
```